# Обработка событий мыши в Java FX

Tags: javafx, события

Необходимо повесить обработчик событий:

```
public class CustomButton extends Button implements EventHandler<MouseEvent>   {

public CustomButton() {
    super("myButton");
}

@Override
public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
    if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED){
        setText("hello");
        System.out.println("button pressed");
    }
}
}
```

main:

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Stage stage = primaryStage;
    stage.setTitle("Simple Application");
    stage.setScene(InitScene());
    stage.show();
}

private Scene InitScene(){
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene myScene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);
    root.getChildren().add (new CustomButton());
    return myScene;
}

public static void main(String... args){
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Проблема:при нажатии на кнопку решительно ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В технологии Java FX заложено отделять графический интерфейс, представленный fxml файлом и обработку событий от графического интерфейса.Вы реализуете приложение на Java FX в стиле awt или swing.

Для того, чтобы сделать обработчик событий необходимо:

В fxml файле:

1. В корневом элементе прописать fx:controller = "Путь к классу", где будет описана функция для обработки события
2. В теге элемента, которому хотим навесить событие прописывает атрибут onAction = "#Название функции" в классе обработчика

Comment: спасибо Вам огромное